# Finding if element exists in array

Tags: javascript

in Python, if you use set() and `in` operator, you can see whether an exists in a set in O(1). However, in javascript, is it possible to do the same with the same time complexity? I have usually done

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
if (arr.indexOf(3) != -1) return true; // element exists!
```

without being really sure about its efficiency.

Comment: Well indexOf() is the proper way to check for an element in an array. As for the efficiency I suppose you'd need to run some tests.

Comment: You can change `if (arr.indexOf(3) != -1) return true;` to `return arr.indexOf(3) != -1;` because the statements returns true.

Comment: Why do you need the answer so quickly? You can set up an O(1) operation by putting everything in an object.

Comment: Not directly. It depends on how its implemented in the engine. You could transform your array into a map, which would give you `O(1)` lookup time, but then you'd lose array semantics.

Comment: I am quite surprised by this. Then, if you had an array whose size is 1Billion and you have to check whether "x" exists in the array. What is the most conventional way of doing that in javascript? Is not having a hashtable a drawback of javascript?